# Pandas add columns with scalar multiplier

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame like this:

```
           Fe      C     Cr     Mn     Si  
26      85.44   0.15  9.833  0.406  0.087  
27      85.44   0.15  9.833  0.406  0.087  
28      85.44   0.15  9.833  0.406  0.087
```

I have other columns, but I can get all the elemental column using:

```
ele = ['Fe', 'C', 'Cr', 'Mn', 'Si']
```

`data[ele]` shows me the portion of the dataframe I'm interested in. Now, I have a dictionary which stores all the atomic number corresponding to those keys:

```
AN = {'Fe': 5, 'C': 10, 'Cr': 15, 'Mn': 20, 'Si': 25}
```

The weighted atomic number would be

```
data[AN] = AN['Fe'] * data['Fe']/100 + AN['C'] * data['C']/100 + ..
```

I have about 25 elements, so it's impractical to write the above equation by hand. I can make individual contribution into column in a for loop:

```
for e in ele:
    data['AN_' + e] = data[e] * AN[e] / 100
```

Then I can add them together to get the new value. But I don't want to create all these useless columns.  Alternatively, I can initialize with an empty column and then add them in a for loop.

```
data['AN'] = 0
for e in ele:
    data['AN'] += data[e] * AN[e] / 100
```

I was wondering, is there any one liner (without the for loop) to get the same effect?

The result should be

```
26       5.8649
27       5.8649
28       5.8649
```

Here, for the first three entry, all the elemental composition is same so it's returning the same value.

Comment: So what is your expected result?

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
df.mul(AN,axis=1).sum(axis=1)/100
```

---

If there are more columns:

```
ele = ['Fe', 'C', 'Cr', 'Mn', 'Si']
df.loc[:,ele].mul(AN,axis=1).sum(axis=1)/100
```

**Output:**

```
26    5.8649
27    5.8649
28    5.8649
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is working perfect! Would it also coerce the nan value to be zero? or it will return nan for the whole sum?

Comment: the sum and mul function treat the NaN values ​​as 0, Out of curiosity:  we can avoid them like this: `df.mul(AN,axis=1).sum(axis=1,min_count=1)/100`.But given your goal of NaN being interpreted as 0 this is not necessary!

Comment: Tell me if you have any problem with the NaN values. We can always use `df = df.fillna(0)` and then apply mul!:)

Comment: nan values are taken care of within `df.mul`, we don't need to use `fillna`, though I'm using it to be on the safe side

Comment: df.mul has a parameter *fill_value* which you can specify to treat the missing/NaN values. 

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html

Comment: you are right ! @exan but the sum function convert to 0 
so this is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.dot` with `dict_value`

```
df.dot(list(AN.values()))/100

Out[154]:
26    5.8649
27    5.8649
28    5.8649
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Would it also coerce the nan value to be zero? or it will return nan for the whole sum?

Comment: this return `NaN` but you could use: `df.fillna(0).dot(list(AN.values()))/100`:)

Comment: `dot`  returns all `NaN` if you have any `NaN` in either `df` or `dict`